# How do you compute minimum from pandas data frame columns, without creating temporary column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, min

Suppose, I have a pandas data frame `df` with columns `A`, `B` and `C`. I would like to compute the row-wise minimum from arithmetic operator on the columns, specifically `df['D']=min(df['A']+dF['B']*3, df['C']*np.sqrt(12))`. I have seen related questions, and it would seem like I would need to first create two columns for the arguments in the `min` function, and them perform `min` of `axis =1`. I was wondering if there was another way, without creating the temporary columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without creating new columns, you can use `apply`:

```
df['D'] = df.apply(lambda x: min(x['A'] + x['B']*3, x['C']*np.sqrt(12), axis=1)
```

But it's best just do:

```
df['D'] = np.mininum(df['A']+dF['B']*3, df['C']*np.sqrt(12))
```

which creates two intermediate columns/series but is much faster thanks to vectorization.

Comment: Beats me to it.  `apply` also takes a `dict` of `col`: `func` as well.